# SharePoint online- How to remove space between web parts in modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-pages

I have a text web part and then a promoted link web part from (classic SP) added in the modern page and there is a lot space between these web parts, which makes the page look blank.

Is there a way to remove this empty space.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Deploy [react-script-editor](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to your tenant so you could the webpart to this page, then you could add custom CSS/JavaScript to this page add custom CSS to reduce the margin.